# How do I prevent Firefox/IE from formatting feeds?

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, firefox, xslt

I wrote an XSLT for RSS feeds and it works fine in Chrome. However, FF and IE have a default feed formatter, so they ignore my XSLT. Is there a way to prevent FF/IE from formatting my feeds and use my XSLT instead?

Edit: I'm looking for something to add in my XML file, not how to change FF/IE settings.

Comment: How do you apply the stylesheet with Chrome? Do you insert a reference to your stylesheet in the RSS document? Is it standalone?

Answer (score 1):

Could you serve an html file instead? In other words does [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryit.asp?filename=cdcatalog) solution look good for you?

in case you cant:

**Fix for firefox:**

1. Make sure the mime type for both source and stylesheet are set to an XML mimetype, namely text/xml or application/xml.
2. The XSLT namespace is http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform. Use the  processing instruction instead of the non-standard xml:stylesheet.
3. Make sure to load XSLT stylesheets from the same domain for security reasons.
4. **For RSS or ATOM feed firefox override styles. A known workaround is to add a sufficiently long XML comment to the beginning of your XML file in order to "push" the  or  tag out of the first 512 bytes, which is analyzed by Firefox to determine if it's a feed or not.**

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ